# Calling React Hook Asynchronously

Tags: reactjs, async-await

Sorry if this is a beginner React question. I am trying to use a React Hook to fetch data and return it to the component asynchronously.

```
    const CallSubmit = async () =>  {
        return await useSubmitForm(tenantForm, datasetForm, entityForm)
    }

    const CallSubmitHook = async () => {
        const submitStatus = await CallSubmit();
        console.log(submitStatus)
        if (submitStatus === true) {
            setCurrentForm(5)
        } else if (submitStatus === false) {
            setCurrentForm(6)
        }
    }
```

`useSubmitForm` is the hook I am having issue with. With this iteration of the code, I get the following error: `Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.`

I've moved the hook call to another function to try to fix this error but it remains. If it needs to be a the top level of the function, how can I conditionally call this once the form is being submitted?

I've tried putting the fetch in a `useEffect` but the issue is that I need the fetch to get its response back before assigning it to a variable. Please let me know how to best implement this?

**EDIT**
Based on Dave's answer, I've restructured my code.

Hook (Sorry for the complexity here. Need to make 3 separate api calls with the data):

```
export default async function useSubmitForm(tenant, dataset, entity) {

let tenantRequestParams = {}
let datasetRequestParams = {}
let entityRequestParams = {}

  const [isSending, setIsSending] = useState(false);
  const [formPostResult, setFormPostResult] = useState()
  const postFormData = async (tenant, dataset, entity) => {
    setIsSending(true);
    const result = await axios.get('token url')
    .then((res) => {
      token = res.data
  
      tenantRequestParams = {
        url: "api1",
        config: {
          headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
          }
        },
        body: JSON.parse(tenant),
      };
    
      datasetRequestParams = {
        url: "api2",
        config: {
          headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
          }
        },
        body: JSON.parse(dataset),
      };
    
      entityRequestParams = {
        url: "api3",
        config: {
          headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
          }
        },
        body: JSON.parse(entity),
      };
    }).then(() => {
      console.log(tenantRequestParams.url,
        tenantRequestParams.body,
        tenantRequestParams.config)
  
      function postTenant() {
        return axios
        .post(
          tenantRequestParams.url,
          tenantRequestParams.body,
          tenantRequestParams.config
        )
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res);
          return res;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
          return error;
        });
      }
  
      function postDataset() {
        return axios
        .post(
          datasetRequestParams.url,
          datasetRequestParams.body,
          datasetRequestParams.config
        )
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res);
          return res;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
          return error;
        });
      }
  
      function postEntity() {
        return axios
        .post(
          entityRequestParams.url,
          entityRequestParams.body,
          entityRequestParams.config
        )
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res);
          return res;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
          return error;
        });
      }
  
      axios.all([postTenant(), postDataset(), postEntity()])
        .then(res => {
          return res;
        }).catch(e => {
          console.error(e)
          return e;
        })
  
    });
    setFormPostResult(result)
  }
  const postFormDataCallback = useCallback(postFormData, [])

return { isSending, success: formPostResult, postFormData: postFormDataCallback };
}
```

And from the component (Simplified version):

```
import useSubmitForm from '../hooks/useSubmitForm';

export default function FormPage(props) {
    const { isSending, success, postFormData } = useSubmitForm();
    const [tenantForm, setTenantForm] = useState('');
    const [datasetForm, setDatasetForm] = useState('');
    const [entityForm, setEntityForm] = useState('');

            return (
                <div>
                    <Form (3 forms, sets values for each to state above)/>
                    <PrimaryButton type="button" onClick={() => {
                        postFormData(tenantForm, datasetForm, entityForm)
                    }}>Submit</PrimaryButton>

                </div>
            )
}
```

With this implementation, I'm having an issue where the destructuring in the component is not working properly (all 3 are undefined `any` values). Am I missing something here?

Comment: where you call `CallSubmitHook`?

Comment: `CallSubmitHook` is called from the button that submits the form

Comment: Don't mix 'await' and '.then()'. Eliminate those 'let' declarations. Try just using a series of const result = await ... calls so you can just read the code top-down without all the .then() and you won't need to move data from inside a .then() to inside the other .then(). Drop Axios.all, Promise.all() is recommended now. You're using the final result(s) and returning them via setFormPostResult(). I'd recommend you start by just getting the token and returning that to your UI. Then add 1 post that takes the token and return its result. Finally the last 2 posts... Baby steps.

Comment: Thanks @Dave. For simplicities sake, I really don't need to use the responses from the 3 api calls. I only need to know, if all three returned a `200 SUCCESS` or not and I'll use frontend validation to make sure good data is submitted. Does this change your recommendation at all?

Comment: No, it just means the success key (value in formPostResult) can be true/false. Start with just the token. Post the form, show the token in the UI. Strip out everything else. When you get that working, update the hook and component so you can show 4 states: before form submit, sending, succeeded, or error. And after that, add the 3 other posts one at a time. If you do all that, you'll be a hooks champ.

Comment: Thanks @Dave, took your advice and got everything working properly! You rock!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hooks belong in the scope of your functional component and must always be called and always be called in the same order.

```
// Everything above is outside the component in global space
const MyComponent = () => {
  // Hooks can only go between these lines... START

  // Hooks can only go between these lines... END

  return (
    <>return your component JSX</>
  )
}
```

**UPDATE**
In your example above `useSubmitForm` is the hook. (Hooks start with the word `use`.) Move the hook to where it belongs. Don't put async in front of the hook. The idea is that you call the hook, it does some work in the background. The hook can return other methods (e.g. postTenantForm() that can you call within your react component.)

**UPDATE2**
Here is some very rough psudo code. You'll need to read some tutorials to get across the finish line, but this is the outline.

```
const useExampleHook = () => {
  const [isSending, setIsSending] = useState(false)
  const [formPostResult, setFormPostResult] = useState()
  const postFormData = async (whichForm, theData) => {
      setIsSending(true)
      const result = await ... // post the data
      setFormPostResult(result)
      setIsSending(false)
  }
  const postFormDataCallback = useCallback(postFormData, [])

  return {isSending, success: formPostResult, postFormData: postFormDataCallback}
}


// Everything above is outside the component in global space
const MyComponent = () => {
  // Hooks can only go between these lines... START
  const {isSending, success, postFormData} = useExampleHook()
  // Hooks can only go between these lines... END

  if (isSending) return <>submitting form</>
  if (success) return <>Tada</>

  return (
    <>
      <button type="button" onClick={()=>{postFormData('formA',{some:data})}}>Save</button>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Hey @Dave, thanks for your answer. I understand they need to be called from the top level of the component. So, if my need is to call this hook after the form is submitted, does this mean hooks are a bad choice for this? Would a regular function call make more sense?

Comment: No hooks are used for exactly this. You want to separate the logic of form submission out of the component. Make the component dumb and have it focus on only the user interface. Pull the strings, do the magic in the component.

Comment: thank you so much for helping with this outline. I've worked on refactoring what I have to follow this design pattern. I've updated my question with more context. If you don't mind, could you take a look? Either way, thank you for the help. I've done some research on destructuring and what you have looks correct so I'm just troubleshooting what I did wrong.